# HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() throws untrappable error

Tags: c#, web, null, request

I am testing a web-service app I wrote in C# (Visual Studio 2015) on a Windows 2003 server. The app runs fine, but when I run the line of code:

```
WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse();
```

where request is an HttpWebRequest instance, the application throws an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Before everyone tells me to go research that error, I have. It doesn't make sense here. The HttpWebRequest is certainly not null, I can access it's properties like URL and UserAgent right before the program crashes. Even more odd, this code is wrapped in a *try..catch* that traps both web exceptions and general exceptions. I've no idea why it isn't trapping this.

But the reason it is happening is because if I try the URL in Internet Explorer (version 8.0 on this old server), I get an "Internet Explorer cannot display the web page" error. I can't even sign in to the site I wish to access. Firefox works fine, but I don't know how to force HttpWebRequest to "be" Firefox (UserAgent has been set to a standard Mozilla string...).

If the web request layer on this old server just won't work (.NET version is 3.5, by the way), that's fine. But I'd like to be able to trap the error. Why doesn't my try..catch work, and does anyone have any idea what would make this very simple code (that works everywhere else) throw a null object error?

### Additional

Here is the whole try..catch:

```
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = GenerateWebRequest(pcMethodName, pcCommand, pcHTTPMethod);
        MessageBox.Show(request.RequestUri.ToString());
        WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse();
        MessageBox.Show("The above line worked!");
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
        lcResult = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    catch (WebException wex)
    {
        lcResult = "ERROR (web exception): " + Environment.NewLine + new StreamReader(wex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lcResult = "ERROR (general exception): " + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message;
    }
```

Shouldn't the final catch trap any general exceptions? To be clear, the error I see is at RUN-TIME -- I cannot debug on this machine because it does not have Visual Studio on it (and that is not an option). So, I have no idea what the process thinks is null. How can I find that out? The reason I know the line:

```
WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse();
```

is the problem is because I put messageboxes between each line until I discovered what line was blowing up. Would putting a "Debug" version of the exe in play offer more debugging info when the app crashes? (NOTE: debug version of EXE does not appear to offer any more information, and I cannot add a `NullReferenceException` because the compiler says the previous "catch" already traps for that...yet it doesn't.).

Comment: Can you post your try..catch? If you are catching 'web exceptions and general exceptions' are you catching NullReferenceExceptions? 

Also when you catch the webexception have you pumped out the response, what is the server telling you?

Comment: What is VS telling you is null?

Comment: And a general catch for `Exception` will catch a NRE @garyamorris. Unless I misunderstood your comment

Comment: I'm checking to see how he's catching the 'general exception', I would assume this means `Exception` but always worth checking.

Comment: I added more information to the original post -- can anyone see more of what might be going on, and most importantly, see why I am unable to trap the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is...I'm an idiot.

The exception WAS being trapped, it went to the WebException branch, and then errored out in there because within that handler I try:

```
lcResult = "ERROR (web exception): " + Environment.NewLine + new StreamReader(wex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

That doesn't work so well when wex.Response is null. And it is null in this case because the request was not establishing a connection in the first place.

A more robust error handler could either nest another try..catch to catch any additional errors, or simply make sure what you are going to use in the handler will always work. I changed my WebException handler to this:

```
    catch (WebException wex)
    {
        if (wex.Response != null)
        {
            lcResult = "ERROR (web exception, response generated): " + Environment.NewLine + new StreamReader(wex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        }
        else
        {
            lcResult = "ERROR (web exception, NO RESPONSE): " + wex.Message + wex.StackTrace;
        }
    }
```

and finally got a meaningful error:

**The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.**

So, it was never getting a connection in the first place, hence no response. This was due to the older IE not supporting HTTPS for this web site. As a quick-and-dirty fix to check if that was the case, I added the catch-all:

```
System.NetServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

and BAM! everything worked. I won't leave that in there, since it's not secure, but it did fix the issue.

So, the error was trappable (was trapped, in fact!) and I figured out why the issue arose in the first place. Thanks to everyone for their help!

Answer (score 0):

The request should not be null. `WebRequest.Create()` should be qualifying your `RequestURI` and will return the following error `Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined`. However I've seen other examples where people have gotten round this like "https://helloworld.comFoo/Bar.html".

The remote name `RequestUri` may be incorrect and you should test it before calling `webRequest.GetResponse()`. The method `WebRequest.Create()` doesn't check this 100%.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by this. How do I test RequestURI, exactly? In my program, I have had a messagebox display the URL right before the line that errors out (this is all a runtime erroring out -- I cannot debug it), and the URL looks fine. In fact, the URL is also saved to a textbox and I can then copy and paste the URL into Firefox -- and it works fine.